Replace blank cells in matrix with 0
I am trying to display a matrix in power bi but some cells are appearing as blank instead of 0.
I created a calculated table and created a measure inside that table to use as the Values parameter for the matrix that looks like this:
Value = IF(ISBLANK(SUM(Sell[Value])), 0, SUM(Sell[Value]) + 0)

OR
Value = SUM(Sell[Value]) + 0

I saw both of these options when searching for a way to achieve my result set but I don't get my expected output. Is there a way to achieve this?
SAMPLE:
main table:
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00

Calculated table
Sell = FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Deal] = "Sell")

Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00

I create a matrix for each table using Counterparty as the rows, Product as the columns, and I create the above measures for the value parameter which I create in each table.
OUTPUT for sell table:
Counterparty   BAR      BUZZ
foo           20.00   (blank)
fizz         (blank)   20.00

EXPECTED OUTPUT for sell table:
Counterparty   BAR      BUZZ
foo           20.00      0
fizz            0     20.00


Can you share a .pbix? What are you seeing?

Can you also provide sample data for your matrix?

@davidebacci I can't share a pbix file, but I have updated my question with a reproducible example. When I create the matrix with the measures, Nothing changes and the empty cells stay empty so I assume I must be doing something wrong

@NickA updated the question with sample data

Difficult to help without seeing which columns from which tables you're using. Which values are not showing that you expect to show? Why do you need calculated tables at all - you would keep those values in a single fact table, create a dimension table for counterparty, product, deal and date and use the dimensions and measures in your matrix.

I don't understand why you are using calculated tables but I will follow the way you want to achieve your result.
The trick here is that you want to show 0 instead of blank when there is no combination between Counterparty and Product.
I created a CC table with the possible combinations :
Combinations = 
CROSSJOIN(
    VALUES('Table'[Counterparty]),
    VALUES('Table'[Product])
)


Then for the measure, I try to sum the values but only for rows where the combination matches the current Counterparty and Product being evaluated :
Value = 
VAR CurrentCounterparty = SELECTEDVALUE(Combinations[Counterparty])
VAR CurrentProduct = SELECTEDVALUE(Combinations[Product])
VAR TotalValue = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sell[Value]),
    Sell[Counterparty] = CurrentCounterparty,
    Sell[Product] = CurrentProduct
)
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(TotalValue), 0, TotalValue)

In the matrix you need to use the Counterparty and Product from the combination table :


If you want to use a measure :
Value = 
IF(
    ISBLANK(SUM(Sell[Value])),
    0,
    SUM(Sell[Value])
)


what should I do instead of calculated tables?

Can you detail what you want to do step by step so we can help you

given the main table above, I need to display 3 matrices: one matirx for a combination between counterparty, product, and BUY dealtype, one matirx for a combination between counterparty, product, and Sell dealtype and a combination between counterparty and product and TOTAL buy/sell

What you did with the cross join is exactly what I need, but now I need to do it for each deal type as well as a total between buy/sell

I see now that I can apply the filter in the CALCULATE function, in the measure instead of creating a seperate table

I replicated your example and tried to follow the logic
